# Problems with ruby 'unroller' gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, trace, require

I'm having a problem using unroller. I have installed the gem and wrote this simple program to help focus on the problem i'm having:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'unroller'

Unroller::trace

def foo(p1, p2)
  puts p1
  puts p2
end

foo("param1", "param2")
```

Running the program yields:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/facets-2.9.3/lib/core/facets/filetest/separator_pattern.rb:5: warning: already initialized constant SEPARATOR_PATTERN
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/facets-2.9.3/lib/core/facets/string/bracket.rb:3: warning: already initialized constant BRA2KET
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- facets/methodspace (LoadError)
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/unroller-1.0.0/lib/unroller.rb:4
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `gem_original_require'
from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
from ./ut:4
```

My ruby version is ruby 1.8.7 (2011-12-28 patchlevel 357). I also installed ruby on my Windows development box and get the same error and that ruby version is 1.9.3 so it does not appear to be related to the version of Ruby I'm on.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks very much in advance!

jon

Comment: Have yo looked at the known errors for `unroller`? Has anyone reported it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug of `unroller` gem, described here: https://github.com/TylerRick/unroller/issues/1. `unroller` automatically requires the latest version of `facets` gem and the version 2.9 breaks it. (BTW gems should never use '>=' when loading dependencies, that's why '~>' is for.)

It's not that difficult to hotfix locally by using bundler and hardcoding `facets` gem to specific version before requiring `unroller` (so the specific `facets` version gets loaded instead of latest 2.9).

create `Gemfile`:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'facets', '2.8.4' 
gem 'termios' # you're gonna need this gem too, for some reason
gem 'unroller'
```

run `bundle install` and then either run the script by `bundle exec ruby test.rb` or require `bundler/setup` in it:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'unroller'
...
```

**UPDATE:** or if you don't wanna deal with bundler, try this first, it could work too:

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'facets', '2.8.4'
require 'unroller'
...
```

Comment: I tried:

    require 'rubygems'
    gem 'facets', '2.8.4'
    require 'unroller'

But that didn't work either. Instead I uninstalled facets-2.9.3 and then installed facets-2.8.4. That lead to:

/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- termios (LoadError)

So I installed termios and that worked.

I searched high and low for some help on this before posting here and never found https://github.com/TylerRick/unroller/issues/1.

Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: Yeah, I linked to that issue ticket in my answer :). It's better to use bundler then.

Comment: Seems like an easy fix for the author of unroller. Begs the question, why hasn't this been fixed?

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Especially since the last working version of facets is really old. https://rubygems.org/gems/facets/versions

Comment: Maybe we can fix it? I posted that to github.com/TylerRick/unroller/issues/1.